# Term for this property of setters which extends "idempotentce."

Tags: terminology, composition

It's so hard to find information on a topic when you don't know the term!

Consider the following code

```
int x = 5;
x = 42;
x = 3;
```

This code can be optimized, because its effects are the same as

```
int x = 3;
```

I'm trying to find the term for this particular property.  I know that, mathematically, they are a left-zero band, which means for any two operations `A` and `B`, `A∘B = A`... only the last operation has any effect.  I also know that this is an extension of the idea of idempotence, which states `A∘A=A` (doing an operation twice is the same as doing it once).  This covers what happens if you do two different operations in the same class.

This seems like a *very* fundamental concept for optimization, so I expect it will have a name, but I have not been able to find it.  I need to relate this concept to non-mathematicians, so saying that the operations form a left-zero band isn't going to cut it.

Comment: You're looking for "dead code elimination"

Comment: @Damon I'm looking for a specific case.  I want to be able to say "these functions have this property which permits dead code elimination."

Comment: ah in that case you might be looking for "dead store".

Comment: @Damon Ahh, that term is close enough to get me started further down the right path.  Thanks!